# The Null Space of Powers of an Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the theorem $8.4$ in the book *Linear Algebra Done Right* as shown below. I cannot understand that why the strict inclusions in the red box hold! In fact, I don't think that just $8.2$ and $8.3$ can result in those strict inclusions. I can understand that why $\text{null} T^{n} \subsetneq \text{null} T^{n+1}$ but don't get it that why the others hold.

Any hint is appreciated. :)

[image]

The references mentioned in the proof are

[image]
[image]

Comment: He has a new edition? Time to head to Springers...

Comment: @Nameless: Yes, it is the third edition! :) But still needs more editions in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had $\operatorname{null}T^m=\operatorname{null}T^{m+1}$ for some $m<n$, then by 8.3 you would have

$$\operatorname{null}T^m=\operatorname{null}T^{m+1}=\operatorname{null}T^{m+2}=\ldots,$$

so in particular

$$\operatorname{null}T^n=\operatorname{null}T^{n+1}=\operatorname{null}T^{n+2}=\ldots,$$

which is what you need. So if the theorem is false then there should **not** exist an $m \le n$ such that $\operatorname{null}T^m=\operatorname{null}T^{m+1}$ which results in the strict inclusions.

Comment: (+1) Thanks! ;) That was so simple! :D I think my confusion was due the the sentence that says *we need only to prove* $\operatorname{null}T^n=\operatorname{null}T^{n+1}$! I was just considering the negation of this! :) In fact, we need only to prove what you said in the answer. :)